# Photoshop 8800 Error only after python creates the file

Tags: javascript, python, subprocess, photoshop, shutil

I have a bit of a weird situation that I will try to explain the best I can.

I am using Python to launch photoshop and run a javascript file. But my goal is for python to generate the javascript first, then run it in photoshop. 
In order to do that I have python copying the javascript file, then replacing a single line of code and running this new copy.

When I run the original javascript file it works as intended with no problems.

When I run the copied javascript file it works as intended with no problems.

When I run the copied javascript file that has the line replaced, it gives me an 8800 error.

At this point, even if I manually type the replaced line to match the original javascript file. I will still get an 8800 error.

Does python somehow write files differently?

Here is the code I am using to replace the copy and replace the javascript contents:

```html
from shutil import copyfile


jsx_file = r'E:\PS\_javascript_constructor_template.jsx'
jsx_file_new = r'E:\PS\_javascript_constructor_template_new.jsx'
copyfile(jsx_file, jsx_file_new)

with open(jsx_file_new, "r") as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    with open(jsx_file_new, "w") as fout:
        fout.write(data.replace("!REPLACEME!",'"E:\PS\MockVar.csv"'))
```

Any ideas?

SIDE NOTE: I am only doing this because I have no idea how to pass an argument from python into the javascript file I am subprocess calling.

I would much rather send an argument to the javascript file than build new files enitrely.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather send an argument to the Photoshop script, I'd recommend using interprocess communication.  You can use the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module in Python and the Socket object in Extendscript to send messages back and forth.  Check out External Communications Tools in the [Adobe Tools Guide](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf) for more information.